# How do I get the font properties of a webpage?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making some changes to my wordpress theme . I want to change font sizes of some elements like pagination . But the style.css file is very confusing . I cannot find the tags used for the element . How do I find the tag used to control the font size of page numbers ?

Comment: Right click an element and click "Inspect" to view the browser's tool for displaying the CSS hierarchy applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you the steps, all browsers have similar procedure

```
Right click->inspect element
```

You can see lots of other useful information, even those which are deep within a number of CSS files.

[image: Screenshot_1]

this screenshot shows the font-family in use

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome Develop tool(F12) or other develop tools to locating your element.

Then you can find which class you should to change

Comment: what about simply Right click -> Inspect Element? :)

Comment: The question is not about IE. Correct me if I'm wrong. IE has F12 and than clicking the Arrow icon (Select element)